# Не создаётся QWidget без Qapplication

Tags: c++, qt

Когда я скомпилировал мой qt проект , он показал такую ошибку. Почему ??

```
QWidget: Cannot create a QWidget without QApplication
```

Я так и не понял в чём проблема.

```
#include<QApplication>
#include"MainWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Этот вопрос, перевод вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36951652/cannot-create-a-qwidget-without-qapplication

Comment: Это нормально,  каждый класс имеет свое предназначение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это очевидно. Вам нужен QApplication для QWidget. Измените QGuiApplication на QApplication, и код будет работать нормально.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "MainWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

А если вы хотите знать   «Почему существуют три основных класса, такие как QApplication, QGuiApplication и QCoreApplication»,то прочтите абзац ниже.

> QCoreApplication является базовым классом, QGuiApplication расширяет
>   базовый класс с помощью функций, связанных с обработкой окон и файлов
>   GUI (не связанных с виджетами, например OpenGL или QtQuick),
>   QApplication расширяет QGuiApplication с функциональностью, связанной
>   с обработкой виджетов.

Разве это не основной пример, доступный в Qt Creator? Вам нужна книга для изучения Qt, и я предлагаю вам прочитать «Qt 4: программирование GUI на С++»  Жасмин Бланшет.

*От переводчика, описание QGuiApplication в книге «Qt 4: программирование GUI на С++» нет.*

---

Из класса QGuiApplication Описание:

Для Qt-приложений, основанных на QWidget, вместо этого используйте QApplication, поскольку он предоставляет некоторые функции, необходимые для создания экземпляров QWidget.

---

От себя добавлю в русском языке очень хороша книга "Qt 5.3 профессиональное программирование на С++" Макс Шлее.

Comment: в контексте вопроса, странно видеть совет почитать книгу по Qt4, в котором `QGuiApplication` нет...

Comment: @Fat-Zer это перевод вопроса, я сам не программист, я газорезчик